# Reference a vector array in multiple cpp files

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How do I reference a vector array in multiple cpp files and headers

The folowing gives the error: 
undefined reference to `function(std::vector >&)'|

main.cpp

```
functionD(arr);
cout << arr[3] << endl;
```

header.h

```
extern vector<string> arr;
int functionD(vector<string> arr);
```

functions.cpp

```
vector<string> arr;

int functionD(vector<string>& arr){

arr.push_back("0");
arr.push_back("1");
arr.push_back("2");
arr.push_back("3");
arr.push_back("4");
arr.push_back("5");
arr.push_back("6");
arr.push_back("7");

return 1;
```

}

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the relevant functions.

Comment: Your example isn't clear. In functions.cpp, you are only using the argument `arr`, not the global `arr`?

Comment: int function(vector<string> *&* arr); in header.h

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Having a global variable can get confusing. Could you pass the `arr` from main into your functions?

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Comment: in main.cpp line:   functionD(arr);

Comment: You are confusing the readers and compiler when you use the same name for function parameters as global variables.  I recommend renaming the parameter.

Comment: You don't need to pass global variables.  Access them directly.